# How to automate the creation of product types?

Tags: commerce

I'm using Drupal 9 with Commerce 2. I have a large number of product types that need to be created. I have for each product type which fields need to be added. Let's say this information is stored in a json (I can vary this if the solution requires it). I was wondering if there is a way to create a module or something that iterates through this json file, and it creates all the product types. If there is, how would I go about implementing this?

I found some code examples with which I can create products programmatically [here](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-management/code-recipes). I'm just not entirely sure how I would use this code inside a custom module.

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: We do something quite like this, including not only adding but also updating the items if the data changes. I think the answer here would depend on whether you intend to execute this manually, say, by uploading a file, or whether you want to automate to work on an ongoing basis.

Comment: @cilefen I appreciate the comment! I would rather execute it manually (upload the file).

Comment: It looks like some modules exist which do that, like https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_import and https://www.drupal.org/project/entities_import. They may work as-is for you, or, you could modify or extend them.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, just custom code all the way down. That said, it may be to your advantage *not* to have a proliferation of product types. They do create overhead on your site. Might be better simply to have optional fields on fewer, especially if their creation will be automated? Could always have a sub-type field on the product type itself that controls which fields are shown on the edit form via form states and even make various fields conditionally required.

Comment: I see... Would, for example, 200 different product types be too many? I like your suggestion though.

Comment: I wouldn't architect a site that way, but you can always run testing on it. Just pay attention to rendering individual products and product lists.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I havent done this exactly with Commerce Entities, but I have done with custom entities using Migrate API.

What you can do is provide json or csv migrate source to migration and map those fields accordingly in `my_products_migration.yml` file , you can use contribute modules like, migrate_plus, migrate_source_csv  you can even refer [migrate_json_example](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/-/tree/6.0.x/migrate_json_example) module from migrate_plus which has a reference example for products migration.

You can refer [commerce migrate documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/commerce-migrate) for additional details

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the information. I'll see what I can do with it.